# How to maintain a separate values file for a dependency Helm subchart that is shared with the parent chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm building a Helm chart that depends on another chart (let's say, "kafka" from bitnami repo). I declared this other chart as a dependency in my `Chart.yaml`:

```
dependencies:
- name: kafka
  version: 14.0.5
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

Now I can set the values for this dependency chart in the top-level `kafka` section of my `values.yaml`. So far, so good.

What if I also need to run "kafka" chart independently with the same values? Let's say I extract them into a separate `kafka-values.yaml`. In this case, will I be able to reuse this separate file when I'm deploying the parent chart?

I understand that if I simply do `--values kafka-values.yaml` when deploying the parent chart, the values will be attached to the root scope instead of the `kafka` scope and "kafka" subchart won't see them.

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right that it is a possibility for you to create an extra values file to pass into your chart. So let's say you create your kafka-values.yaml file with some values. If you now install your parent chart with the option --values kafka-values.yaml, this file will now be overlayed onto the values.yaml that is inside your helm chart. You can now also use this kafka-values.yaml to do the same thing if you would like to just install the kafka chart.

In general, the order of overlaying values in helm follows the order of this [list](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/). This means that any values passed into a chart, either by external file or individual values will overlay onto the values.yaml file in the chart. If the same values are specified, the values.yaml value will be overridden. If it has not been defined in a "lower priority", the values will be overlayed into the values for the chart.

**EDIT**

The main difference between what you are trying to do is the fact that your kafka-values.yaml for your parent chart need to be indented under the `kafka:` scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you have something listed as a dependency of your chart, Helm will always try to install it connected to the parent chart.  It won't look for another installation elsewhere in the cluster or try to import or export values from another Helm release.

You might reasonably want to use Kafka as a messaging or eventing bus across several services.  In this case you don't necessarily want Kafka tied to a single service; you could install it at the cluster level, or on dedicated hardware, or use a cloud-hosted version of it.  This means you need two things: a setting to say whether or not to install Kafka as a dependency, and a setting to point to the Kafka bootstrap server(s).

```yaml
# values.yaml

# kafka has settings for the Kafka broker.
kafka:
  # enabled indicates whether to install Kafka as part of this release.
  enabled: true

  # bootstrapServers is a comma-separated list of HOST:PORT indicating
  # the location of at least one known Kafka broker.  Only used if
  # enabled is false.
  bootstrapServers: ''
```

In your chart requirements, you can [specify a condition](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#tags-and-condition-fields-in-dependencies) to cause the dependency to only be installed if the value is set:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - name: kafka
    version: ^14
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    condition: kafka.enabled     # <--- add this line
```

Finally, you need to use template logic to pass the correct Kafka address to the application.

```yaml
env:
  - name: KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS
{{- if .Values.kafka.enabled }}
    value: {{ .Release.Name }}-kafka:9092
{{- else }}
    value: {{ .Values.kafka.bootstrapServers }}
{{- end }}
```

And then when you install the chart, you can specify to use either a local or remote Kafka.

```sh
helm install chart-with-local-kafka .
# --set kafka.enabled=true  # on by default

helm install chart-with-remote-kafka . \
  --set kafka.enabled=false \
  --set kafka.bootstrapServers=kafka.infra.example.com:9092
```